# bypass apache when svn repo stored locally?

Tags: svn, version-control

Not really sure how to word this question--which is making searching rather fruitless,

but essentially our team keeps a lot of our code in an svn repo. I always have accessed it through apache.
so to checkout i'd just

`svn co http://192.168.1.x/path/to/project .`

This generally works, but I often find myself doing work on the machine that also hosts the svn repos. Bad idea, maybe, but we are a very small shop. Anyhow, the point being Apache gets a bit upset if I request too much at once. Would there be a way where I could simply checkout it out locally, say `

`svn co /srv/svn/path/to/project .`

I feel I should get faster results if I don't send it through Apache. Is this data all going through the nic?

Answer (score 1):

> This generally works, but I often find myself doing work on the machine that also hosts the svn repos. Bad idea, maybe, but we are a very small shop.

Indeed, it is a bad idea. You lose all Subversion security and your hook scripts may fail.

Fix the root cause - figure out why Apache gets cranky & correct that. Don't bypass it for convenience.

Comment: I should mention that the machine is only accessible locally. Further, it is backed up daily to both an onsite device and this mysterious thing called the cloud. The bypass idea is a theory. Does apache realize at first that I am local? or does it simply return the data out the ethernet port, out to the router, and back to the ethernet? I am trying to reduce a hop.

Comment: You're probably hitting I/O contention - you're trying to read & write very quickly on the same spindle, both for the checkout operation on the surface and any scratch space Apache needs along the way. Do you have multiple drives such that you can check out to one where the repository itself isn't hosted?

Comment: no, I've lobbied for them. Why our dev machine has a single 2tb 7.2k drive boggles my mind. We actually did just replace our production server. so there are a couple 15k drives laying around. I should pilfer those, good point. Ultimately, I think your analysis is likely spot on.

Comment: Even with separate servers connected to a SAN, I had checkout performance issues for one project when both the SVN server and the destination server were on the same SAN. Increasing memory allocated to the SVN server helped, but I think moving the destination server to another SAN altogether had the best impact on performance. If you're being forced to use a sub-par environment for development, factor that extra time & trouble into your delivery estimates. When there's a demonstrated additional time/money cost to getting your work done, progress will be made.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, while this didn't directly answer my question it deserves many up votes. Thanks for taking your time to address my root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Apache just provides a location with a well-known URL for the repository and maybe some security like additional authentication.

You can checkout the repo from a local directory:

```
svn co file:///var/svn/repos/project .
```

However, your end users will have to be able to access `/var/svn/repos`. So if you checkout on the server, it will just data directly from disk. If you make this directory available as a network location, your users will access it through the network.